# rake assets:precompile aborting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I was able to precompile assets an hour ago, but now the rake task is aborting. I also check it on another app, and it's aborting there too. I had interrupted a push to Heroku rather abruptly, and haven't been able to precompile since then.

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
undefined method `prerequisites' for nil:NilClass
/Users/mm/Sites/quoraquora/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Line 7 of the rake file is this code Enki::Application.load_tasks

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

Enki::Application.load_tasks
```

I also did a bundle update, but it didn't change anything. Prior to trying to run the rake task, I abruptly stopped a push to Heroku because I had forgot to compile the assets. Not sure if that could have caused anything. Interestingly, the application still runs on localhost.

I tried to run bundle exec rake assets:precompile on another app, and I also got an error, albeit a different one that says it can't locate 'uglifier' even though that gem is installed.

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby /Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- uglifier
  (in /Users/mm/Sites/railshangman/app/assets/javascripts/admin.js)

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions...]

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

This is the full trace from the first abort. Can anyone explain? The problem seems to be beyond the scope of one specific app, because `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` was working fine on every app one hour ago.

```
Macintosh-3:coffeelover mm$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
rake aborted!
undefined method `prerequisites' for nil:NilClass
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.0.1/lib/rspec/rails/tasks/rspec.rake:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.0.1/lib/rspec-rails.rb:10:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `instance_exec'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `block in load_tasks'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `each'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `load_tasks'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:423:in `block in load_tasks'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:423:in `load_tasks'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:145:in `load_tasks'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/mm/Sites/coffeelover/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:583:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Are you using the Cedar stack? If so I would run a `rake asset:clean` then check in any removed public file that were created during the precompile, then let heroku run the assets:precompile automatically when you deploy.

Comment: @ChrisBarretto I get the same error when I run rake asset:clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your version of rake and rspec-rails

```
bundle update rspec-rails
bundle update rake
```

Comment: Maybe this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922256/rake-dbmigrate-aborted

Comment: It required an rspec-rails update but I had to set the version manually in the gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

I had to update my version of rspec-rails to 2.6.0 (from 2.0). Strangely, this did not happen automatically if I deleted the gemfile.lock and did bundle update. I had to manually set the version in the Gemfile.